Application Insights shows failures as if they are in the library and not in my application
I have integrated Application Insights into my Spring Boot application. When there are exceptions it lists location of the exceptions as if they are occurring in the library level. But I cannot fix those libraries. Would be useful if it lists location of the exceptions in my application.
In other words now it shows the exception occurs at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions:111 but it is very useless for me. Is it possible to make it so that it show location in my own app like at com.example.test.MyOwnService:123?


Use a custom error handler or an interceptor in the application to log more detail about the exceptions, & can you please provide the code it would be more useful to trace.


Is it possible to make it so that it show location in my own app like at com.example.test.MyOwnService:123

If you're using default Spring Boot Application Insights integration, it will capture the full stack trace. If you want to filter out unnecessary library-level stack traces by adjusting the logging settings.
You can add a custom filter to control the logging level and capture stack traces more relevant to your code.
In the Spring Boot code, whenever you catch exceptions, you can send them to Application Insights with custom properties.
MyOwnService.java:
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyOwnService {

    @Autowired
    private TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

    public void someMethod() {
        try {
            // Some code that might throw exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Capture the exception with custom properties
            telemetryClient.trackException(e, Collections.singletonMap("CustomLocation", "com.example.test.MyOwnService:123"));
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

To avoid libraries trace, customize the telemetry by overriding how exceptions are tracked. use a custom TelemetryProcessor or adjust the sampling settings.
For instance, you can create a processor that modifies the ExceptionTelemetry to ensure it captures the appropriate location details
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.TelemetryProcessor;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.ExceptionTelemetry;

public class CustomTelemetryProcessor implements TelemetryProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Telemetry item) {
        if (item instanceof ExceptionTelemetry) {
            ExceptionTelemetry exceptionTelemetry = (ExceptionTelemetry) item;
            // Modify the stack trace or add custom properties here
            exceptionTelemetry.getProperties().put("CustomLocation", "com.example.test.MyOwnService:123");
        }
        return true;
    }
}

Traces only when exceptions triggers:

Custom Location:

